# How clone entity in JPA and set id from old entity to some column of new entity?

Tags: java, jpa

I have method for insert entity to DB;

```
public PollEvent insertPollEvents(PollEvent pollEvent) {
        PollEvent merge = null;
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            pollEvent.setSendDate(new Date());
            pollEvent.setStatus(0);
            pollEvent.setType(1);
            pollEvent.setPollEvent(pollEvent);
            pollEvent.setSms(null);
            pollEvent.setId(null);
            pollEvent.setAnswerRecived(null);
            pollEvent.setRecivedDate(null);
            pollEvent.setQuestionSend("опрос 2");
            em.detach(pollEvent);
            merge = em.merge(pollEvent);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            em.clear();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return merge;
    }
```

I select entity and change some fields. After that I want set  `pollEvent.setPollEvent(pollEvent);` and save entity to DB and return new entity. It work fine but `setPollEvent` set id from new entity. For example I need:

```
id field1 field2 pool_id
1   xxx    xxx    NULL
2   xxx    xxx    1
```

But I have

```
id field1 field2 pool_id
1   xxx    xxx    NULL
2   xxx    xxx    2
```

It is because I make `em.detach(pollEvent);` and my old id lose. How curectly meke this?

Comment: Not sure I got it completely. Are you trying to insert new PollEvent entities in the database and associate the poll_id of these new entities to PollEvent entity passed in the insertPollEvents(...)

Comment: Also once you create clone of the existing object and save the clone do you intent to retain the old object in the DB? Do you want to clone all the fields of the old object into new object except poll_id, because  I see that you are nullifying most of the fields in the "pollEvent" object.

Comment: and what state is "pollEvent" in when you call detach on it? because if it isn't managed by that "em" then your logic is flawed (whatever it is you're trying to do ...)